# How to install pymssql to Python 3.4 rather than 2.7 on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: python, linux, pymssql

I'm not overly familiar with Linux and am trying to run a Python script that is dependent upon Python 3.4 as well as pymssql.  Both Python 2.7 and 3.4 are installed (usr/local/lib/[PYTHON_VERSION_HERE]).  pymssql is also installed, except it's installed in the Python 2.7 directory, not the 3.4 directory.  When I run my Python script (python3 myscript.py), I get the following error:

File "myscript.py", line 2, in 
  import pymssql
ImportError: No module named 'pymssql'

My belief is that I need to install pymssql to the Python 3.4 folder, but that's my uneducated opinion.  So my question is this:

How can I get my script to run using Python 3.4 as well as use the pymssql package (sorry, probably wrong term there)?

I've tried many different approaches, broken my Ubuntu install (and subsequently reimaged), and at this point don't know what to do.  I am a relative novice, so some of the replies I've seen on the web say to use ENV and separate the versions are really far beyond the scope of my understanding.  If I have to go that route, then I will, but if there is another (i.e. easier) way to go here, I'd really appreciate it, as this was supposed to just be a tiny thing I need to take care of but it's tied up 12 hours of my life thus far!  Thank you in advance.

Comment: run pip install pymssql

Comment: LetzerWille, thank you for your reply.  I did run that, but the first time I ran it it installed to the 2.7 directory, and if I try to run it again it says I don't need to because it's already installed.

Comment: then you have to disable the path to Pyhton 2.7 when installing pymssql

Comment: Again, thank you LetzerWille.  Could you give me a shove in the right direction on doing so.  I really don't even know where to look and at this point my grey matter has melted after a day of guesswork.

Comment: What are PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME set to? Use a fully qualified directory path to 'pip' to make sure you are executing the correct one.

Comment: you might have python 3's pip installed as something like `pip3` or `pip-3.4`, or you could just do `python3 -m pip install ...`

Comment: RobertB - Thank you for your reply.  Using "printenv" I'm not seeing any environment variables of those two names.  Also, I just searched the drive for "pip" and I think (if I'm reading this correctly) that it's only installed under 2.7.  I find a folder titled "pip" in "usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages", but I don't find the equivalent in the same relative location under python3.4, so I don't know what the fully qualified directory path should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [virtual environments](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#creating-virtual-environments) instead of system paths or environment scripts. [See official Python package installation guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html).

All you need to do is to

```
# Create fresh Python environemnt
virtualenv -p python3.4 my-venv

# Activate it in current shell
source my-venv/bin/activate

# Install packages
pip install mysqlclent
```

[Note that mysqlclient is Python 3.x compatible version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient).

Answer (score 2):

It is better if when you run python3.4 you can have modules for that version.
Another way to get the desire modules running is install pip for python 3.4

sudo apt-get install python3-pip

Then install the module you want

python3.4 -m pip install  pymssql

Comment: Thank keir. This helped me out.